# UIFont for Label not cooperating with size settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uifont

I want to make a game title but I can't seem to make the font larger.  Here's what I have.  I opted to not use CGRectMake initializer setting because I wanted to just set the x and y positions, not the size of the label (which I presumed would've been dictated by the size: portion of the UIFont method below).  The 100.0 is no different from size 40.0.

```
    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    CGRect frame = title.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 30;
    frame.origin.x = 100;
    title.frame= frame;
    title.text = @"TWINSTONES";
    title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TWINSTONES" size:100.0];
    [title setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:1.0]];
    title.numberOfLines = 0;
    [title sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:title];
```

Comment: Right...........the fontWithName is completely wrong....sorry.

Comment: A follow up thought though...how do I center the label on the screen?  Instead of setting the frame.origin.x?

Comment: [title setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];  // will center in frame

Comment: thanks, didn't even know that existed until now